# Exception thrown. Dynamic array and operation stack

Tags: c, dynamic

THIS IS THE DYNAMIC ARRAY:

```
typedef struct
{
    TElement* elems;
    int length;   //length of the array
    int capacity;  //capacity of the array
}
DynamicArray;
```

the **EXCEPTION** is thrown in the getLength (Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**arr** was 0xFFFFFFFFD03ED950. occurred):

```
    TElement get(DynamicArray* arr, int pos)
    {
        return arr->elems[pos];
    }

    int getCapacity(DynamicArray* arr)
    {
        if (arr == NULL) return -1;
        return arr->capacity;
     }
```

I have tried to make this function type DynamicArray but it doesn't work

```
    int getLength(DynamicArray* arr)
    {
        if (arr == NULL) return -1;
        return arr->length;
    }
```

**here is where the length is obviously used as an int**
       //HERE I USE THE LENGTH:

```
    void add(DynamicArray* arr, TElement t)
    {
        if (arr == NULL) return 0;

        if (arr->elems == NULL) return 0;

        //resize the array, if necessary

        if (arr->length == arr->capacity)
            resize(arr);
        arr->elems[arr->length++] = t;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't said exactly what exception you are seeing (error message?). If you use the debugger, you should be able to narrow down where the exception is being thrown. The code you are showing isn't sufficient to determine whether you've allocated your data structures properly. If you don't use the debugger, you'll need to, more tediously, start looking at your code where you first allocate your data structures and follow the logic to see where it went wrong. The exception is likely due to accessing an invalid pointer or an array index out of range.

Comment: The exception is: Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**arr** was 0xFFFFFFFFD03ED950. occurred

Comment: That's basically what I was talking about then: you have a bad pointer or index somewhere. Read my prior comment about how to try to find it.

Comment: in the debugger it alerts me about the elems,length(which i return in the function) and the capacity: 0xffffffffd03ed950 {elems=??? length=??? capacity=??? } What i do no understand is why there is no exception for the function getCapacity, since it's implemented the same

Comment: The resize() function seems suspicious. I would guess that your structure is not NULL but no longer points to a valid address after the resize().

Comment: int resize(DynamicArray* arr)
{
 if (arr = NULL)
  return 0;

 arr->capacity *= 2;

 //we allocate new memory ->copy everything-> deallocate the old memory

 TElement* aux = (TElement*)malloc(arr->capacity * sizeof(TElement));
 if (aux == NULL)
  return -1;

 for (int i = 0; i < arr->length; i++)
  aux[i] = arr->elems[i];
 free(arr->elems);
 arr->elems = aux;

 return 0;
}

Comment: I think you need to correct like this: `if (arr = NULL) return 0; arr->capacity = 2;` -> `if (arr == NULL) return 0; arr->capacity *= 2;`.